# How to execute series of select query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am new to Hql. I am facing problem in select query. I am actually doing group rename option. For that first I am looking for pericular Id. next if there is no groupname of new groupname then I am updating old groupname. My method is like this.

```
private void renameGroup(String ogname, String gname , String clientid) {
    //Here   ogname="group7"
    //       gname="group8"

    System.out.println("Old group name2="+ogname);
    Session hSession = HibernateSession.getHibernateSession();
    Transaction transaction = hSession.beginTransaction();


    String hql= "select groupname from GroupDetails where clientid=:clientid  and groupname=:oldGroupName";
    Query query = hSession.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("clientid", Integer.valueOf(clientid));
    query.setParameter("oldGroupName",ogname );
    List<Object[]> groupList = (List<Object[]>) query.list(); // This has groupname [group7]

    if(!(groupList.isEmpty()))
    {
        Session hSession2 = HibernateSession.getHibernateSession();
        Transaction transaction2 = hSession.beginTransaction();
        String hql2= "select groupname from GroupDetails where clientid =:clientid  and groupname=:newGname";
        Query query2 = hSession2.createQuery(hql2);
        query2.setParameter("clientid", Integer.valueOf(clientid));
        query2.setParameter("newGname",gname );
        List<Object[]> groupList2 = (List<Object[]>) query2.list();//Here it has to be empty so that I can update but it also has [group7]

        if(groupList2.isEmpty())
        {// So it never come to this block
            String hql3="update GroupDetails set groupname=:newGroupName where clientid=:clientid  and groupname=:ogname";
            Query query3 = hSession.createQuery(hql2);
            query3.setParameter("newGroupName", gname);
            query3.setParameter("clientid",Integer.valueOf(clientid));
            query3.setParameter("ogname",ogname);
            int res = query3.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Command successfully executed....");
            System.out.println("Numer of records effected due to update query"+res);
        }

    }


}
```

Observe my comments for better understand of my problem. I think problem is in session and transaction. but I am not getting. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: I am not getting your code exactly and comments.In second query you are comparing group name = newGroup and as per your comment you are getting list of groupname = oldGroup.How it is possible?

Comment: yes "newGroup" is a just string it has to be empty.

Comment: yes but as per your comment you have written but it also has [group7].what is it?It is creating confusion

Comment: I mean after executing second query the list what i will get has to be empty but I have [group7] in obj `groupList2`

Comment: don't you need to do transaction.commit() ?

Comment: why is there a transaction2? are you using more than 1 transaction?

Comment: Yes I got it solved. I took new session and transaction before every query and closed both after executing of each query.